# Coordinates/charts for the space of k-tuples of orthonormal vectors (a.k.a. Stiefel manifold)

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, differential-topology, parametrization

Is there a reasonably natural way to create an atlas (with coordinate charts) for the space of $k$-tuples of orthonormal vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$? (Obviously $k \le n$.) The dimension of the desired space is
$$\sum_{i=1}^k n - i = k(n - \tfrac{1}{2}k - \tfrac{1}{2})$$
if I am not mistaken.

**Naïve approach**
Choose a random matrix and do Gram-Schmidt orthonormalization (or possibly a more numerically stable alternative, like Householder transforms). Then figure out how to fix $n^2 - k(n - \tfrac{1}{2}k - \tfrac{1}{2})$ parameters to get a dense open subset, and find different ways to do this so that the open sets cover the entire space.

I would accept an answer based on the naïve approach, but I hope something better ("more natural") comes along.

**Notes**

- I said all $k$-tuples, but really I'm okay with just the connected component containing $(\mathbf{e}_1, \dotsc, \mathbf{e}_k)$.
- What I'm actually hoping to do is plug this into a computer. So computational aspects matter too, although as a former mathematician my first concern is for naturality.

Comment: The natural way to do this is via the theory of homogenous spaces - the orthogonal group $O(n)$ acts transitively on the set of $k$-frames with isotropy subgroup $O(n-k)$, so your space should be the quotient of Lie groups $O(n)/O(n-k)$. You can think of this as being a "half-way point" to the Grassmannian $\mathrm{Gr}(k,n) = O(n)/(O(k) \times O(n-k)$, whose construction you should be able to find a lot of literature a bout.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis: A nice thought -- is there a non-computationally-awful way of doing this? I've been deliberately avoiding quotient spaces for computational reasons.

Comment: For the Grassmannian we usually get local coordinates like this: any $k$-plane sufficiently close to a given one $\Pi$ can be uniquely represented by the graph of a linear function $\Pi \to \Pi^\perp$, so there is a geometrically natural chart centred on $\Pi$ consisting of $(n-k)\times k$ matrices. (In fact, such a chart can be made to cover almost the whole manifold - things only go wrong at $k$-planes that non-trivially intersect $\Pi^\perp$, which form a measure-zero set.) See if you can work out how to adapt this idea.

Comment: Apparently this space is called a [Stiefel manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiefel_manifold), so this should be pretty googlable.

Comment: @Anthony: Thanks for figuring out the name! I'm aware of the Grassmannian coordinates you describe, but a projection of an orthonormal frame is almost never orthonormal. It can usually (outside a set of measure zero) be made so using e.g. Gram-Schmidt, but at this point we're back to a version of the inelegant "naïve approach" I outlined in the question.

Comment: Would the exponential mapping $\exp:{\frak so}(n)\to {\rm SO}(n)$ restricted to (a nbhd of $0$ in the) orthogonal complement of ${\frak so}(k)\oplus{\frak so}(n-k)$ and postcomposed with the projection to the Stiefel manifold ${\rm O}(n)\to{\rm V}(k,n)$ be a chart around the image of the identity matrix $I\in{\rm SO}(n)$ within ${\rm V}(k,n)$?

Comment: @arctictern: If you count dimensions, I think you'll find that $\mathfrak{so}(k) \oplus \mathfrak{so}(n-k)$ does not span $\mathfrak{so}(n)$.

Comment: Even if you could find a nice subspace of $\mathfrak{so}(n)$ that maps isomorphically (in a neighborhood) onto $V(n,k)$ via the exponential map: I'm specifically interested in the case that $k \ll n$. So computing an $n \times n$ matrix just to take the first $k$ rows (or columns) is computationally awful.

Comment: I'm not sure what your point is in regards to ${\frak so}(k)\oplus{\rm so}(n-k)$ being a proper subspace of ${\frak so}(n)$. You didn't ask for a chart for ${\rm SO}(n)$, after all. Although I should have just said orthogonal complement of ${\frak so}(k)$, since ${\rm V}(k,n)={\rm O}(n)/{\rm O}(n-k)$. I was confusing it with ${\rm Gr}(k,n)={\rm O}(n)/{\rm O}(k)\times{\rm O}(n-k)$. Dunno if it can be turned into a computationally efficient version, but it seemed natural.